# Not able to COPY a downloaded artifact into a docker image

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-artifacts

I am new to github actions, I am trying to build an docker image with an artifact from maven repo. The process works fine until the COPY stage, I received the following error:

#6 [2/3] COPY /tmp/eb47ef3d-5bd0-4ad9-a975-fe90395c5477/norconex-collector-http-3.0.2.zip /nxer
#6 ERROR: failed to calculate checksum of ref 1fc30fa1-1c27-471d-88c5-f9ef7be1c990::2dvvtji2m8thd1cu1if5dg2w1: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2321225556/tmp/eb47ef3d-5bd0-4ad9-a975-fe90395c5477: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2321225556/tmp/eb47ef3d-5bd0-4ad9-a975-fe90395c5477: no such file or directory

This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
From ubuntu:22.04
ARG DL_FILE

COPY $DL_FILE /nxer
```

The $DL_FILE variable gets its value from the docker build command, which refer to the location of the downloaded artifact.

In my github actions workflow:

```
jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Download Maven Artifact
      id: download-maven-artifact
      uses: clausnz/github-action-download-maven-artifact@master
      with:
        url: 'https://repo1.maven.org'
        repository: 'maven2'
        groupId: 'com.norconex.collectors'
        artifactId: 'norconex-collector-http'
        version: '3.0.2'
        extension: 'zip'

    - name: Output file path in container
      run: |       
        echo "File has been downloaded to ${{ steps.download-maven-artifact.outputs.file }}"
                 
    - name: Build the Docker image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
      with:
        context: .
        push: false  
        build-args: DL_FILE=${{ steps.download-maven-artifact.outputs.file }}
```

I googled it and it looks like the issue is the downloaded artifact is saved outside of the docker context, so when I copy it, the file is not found.

I tried things like adding flag like: context, build-context, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to work around the issue? Thanks

Brian

Tried adding different flag to docker build command

Comment: So the files are just in the wrong place? What if you `cp` or `mv` the files into the context before the build?

Comment: @Bademeister, I thought of that as well, however, the temp docker folder (context: /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2321225556/) is not created until the docker build command is run.

Comment: I would try it without the clausnz/github-action-download-maven-artifact and docker/build-push-action. Or at least build dockert build yourself. It's more work, but you also have more control.